# How to fetch the array? PHP

Tags: php

I try to fetch the data from database.

Example the data is fetched

```
["1","Your Name","2","Cashier"]
```

I want insert this data into database but the result getting is like this example

```
["[&quot;1&quot;","&quot;Your Name&quot;"]
```

But I want the result is this

```
["1","Your Name"]
```

Below the code is that I use to fetch the data

```
            foreach($new_invoice_item as $invoice_item){

                $sale_person = explode(',',$invoice_item['sale_person']);
                $employee = array_chunk($sale_person, 2);

                    foreach($employee as $id) {
                        $statement = $db->prepare('
                        INSERT INTO `selling_employee` (
                            invoice_no, payment_id, category, sale_person, amount, created_at
                        ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                        ');
                        $statement->execute([
                            $invoice_id, $payment_id, 'product', json_encode($employee), $divide_amount, $created_at
                        ]); 
                    }
                  
            }
```

Comment: You are using the wrong approach. You dont need to explode the array and get data data chunk wise. In this case the double quote sign is also attached to it that is creating the issue. Simply use index num for the array and pass it to the insert query

Comment: @JohnDoe Sorry, I dont understand. Could you list the example?